# How to hide and show sections coming from loop on click of button - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 sections coming from loop. Also I have 3 buttons. Here I need to show only first section('one') by default and first button should be active.When I click second button second section should show only and second button should be active..so on. Here is the code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hccv44?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let data of testJson">{{data.name}}</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px"><button>click1</button></div>
<div><button>click2</button></div>
<div><button>click3</button></div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  testJson = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'one'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'two'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'three'
    }
  ];
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wns1fb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easy. You only need a variable for know the section activated.

In "app.component.ts" you will have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  button_selected = 1;
  testJson = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'one'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'two'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'three'
    }
  ];
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And in your app.component.html

```
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let data of testJson">
  <div *ngIf="data.id==button_selected">
    {{data.name}}
  </div>

</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px">
  <button *ngFor="let data of testJson" 
  style="display:block" 
  (click)="button_selected=data.id" 
  [disabled]="button_selected==data.id"
  >
    click {{data.id}}
  </button>
</div>
```

You can try it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcmjaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, instead of disable ,can I change it to different/active color?

Comment: Yes, you can use [ngClass]="condition? 'class1':'class2' "  for decide a specific css class or you can use [ngStyle]="condition? 'styles1':'styles2' "  for chnage directly the style

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage a component library like angular material to have some fancy, toggleable buttons. The you can run the loop over the buttons as well to create as many as you like.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of testJson">
  <div *ngIf="data.id == number">
    {{data.name}}
  </div>
</ng-container>

<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="number" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let data of testJson" [value]="data.id">{{data.name}}</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  number = 1;
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wns1fb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)